# Log in missing after shutdown on MacBook Pro OS X Lion 10.7.5

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Every time our work MBP is shutdown/restarted, only one user log in appears.  After that user(with displayed log in) logs in, the other profiles become visible again.  I wouldn't be surprised if I were missing some sort of profile setting, as I'm not super savvy on a mac.  However after exhausting search resources I'm hoping that someone here on SO has encountered a similar issue. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have FileVault 2 encryption set up? If so, you probably only have one of your users enabled for pre-boot authentication. If this is the problem, you can enable the rest of your users in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy pane -> FileVault tab.

Comment: I'll give this a shot as soon as I can get back on.